# How to collect warnings/notices while JDBC statement is being executed?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.4

I am experiencing an issue with the latest version of PostgreSQL JDBC driver: I can not collect warnings/notices while the prepared statement is still being executed. Warning list only becomes available after the statement returns.

I used this feature with some previous driver version (I guess 9.1), but the implementation of `PgPreparedStatement` has probably changed since then.

What are my options to collect warnings before results are returned?

I created this simple test:

```
public class WarningTest {

    @Test
    public void readWarnings() throws Exception {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test_db", "test_user", "test_password");
        createTestFunction(con);

        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT test_function();");
        SQLWarning[] warnings = new SQLWarning[1];
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override public void run() {
                try {
                    warnings[0] = statement.getWarnings();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Assert.fail("Exception thrown: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }, 3500);
        statement.executeQuery();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        statement.close();

        Assert.assertNotNull(warnings[0]);
        Assert.assertFalse(warnings[0].getMessage().isEmpty());
    }

    private void createTestFunction(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        final PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(
            "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function() RETURNS VOID AS\n"
            + "$BODY$\n"
            + "BEGIN\n"
            + "\tFOR i IN 1..3 LOOP \n"
            + "\t\tRAISE NOTICE 'Tick %', i;\n"
            + "\t\tEXECUTE pg_sleep(1);\n"
            + "\tEND LOOP;\n"
            + "END\n"
            + "$BODY$\n"
            + "\tLANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;");
        statement.execute();
        statement.close();
    }
}
```

It creates a function that runs for 3 seconds and writes a tick at the beginning of each second.

Test passes like this as the timer starts after result is returned. But if you decrease the timer delay from `3500` to `1500` the test will fail even though the database would have issued 2 notices by that time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was introduced with `REL9.4.1210`. Versions `REL9.4.1209` and below work as expected.

[Line 244 of this commit](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/commit/edcdccd658cbf3f2bfd677901f7bebac13a6259b#diff-e517b352b59b7d012c0a772c7e84d3eeL224) is the reason why this no longer works, the warnings were previously added directly to the statement as soon as they were received, but it was re-factored and now they are only available after completion.

[I have raised an issue for this](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/856), as well as a [PR to address it.](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/pull/857)

Comment: I've been watching your effort at GitHub. The bounty is well deserved!

Comment: @BorisSchegolev The change has been merged and should be in the next driver release.